# GNU find all executable files: Equivalent on OS X?

Tags: macos, find

I need to get a list of all things marked as executable on a filesystem. On linux, I would just do:

```
find . -executable -type f
```

But on OS X, find complains:

```
find: -executable: unknown primary or operator
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `perm` operator:

```
find . -perm +0111 -type f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html):

```
mdfind "kMDItemKind == 'Unix Executable File'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just install the GNU findutils from Homebrew and use gfind instead of find.

Answer (score -5):

There is no -executable for mac.
If you want all of the .exe files, you could do:

find . -name "*.exe" -type f

Comment: .exe is not used as an executable extension on OS X. The question asker is looking for the executable bit.